# async - Execute action after loop completed in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I'm trying to develop a synchronous process in node.js, and I have implemented the `async.series` method, but the way of I've implemented is not working as I expect. I expect the second function of the series works after the first function terminate (including the operation of the loop). As the `s3.getObject` is an asynchronous function I'm a few lost how can I implement it correctly.

Resuming: I want to go to the second function after complete the loop and the functions inside the loop.

```
async.series([
  function(cback) {

    console.log("first function series...");

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonUsuariosPerfil.users.length; i++) {

      var usuario = jsonUsuariosPerfil.users[i];

      var paramsUsers = {
        Bucket: 's3.....br/.../users/' + usuario.user,
        Key: 'profiles',
      };

      console.log("loop jsonUsuariosPerfil... " + usuario.user);

      s3.getObject(paramsUsers, function(err, data) {

        if (err) {

          console.log("Error: " + err);
          const message = "Error getting user -> " + err;
          console.log(message);
          callback(message);

        } else {

          var jsonPerfisUsuario = JSON.parse(data.Body);

          var removido = false;

          console.log("found object..." + JSON.stringify(data.Body))

          for (var i = 0; i < jsonPerfisUsuario.profiles.length; i++) {

            var perfil = jsonPerfisUsuario.profiles[i];

            if (perfil.profile == id_grupo) {

              jsonPerfisUsuario.profiles.splice(i, 1);
              removido = true;
              break;

            }

          }

          if (removido) {

            var paramsPut = {
              Bucket: 's3.....br/.../users/' + usuario.user,
              Key: 'profiles',
              Body: JSON.stringify(jsonPerfisUsuario)
            };

            console.log("removido, salvando profiles");

            s3.putObject(paramsPut, function(err2, data2) {

              if (err2) {

                console.log("error putting the file:" + err2);

                var erro = {
                  status: "ERROR_SAVING_FILE"
                };

                generalCallback(null, erro);

              } else {

                console.log("salvo arquivo dos profiles do usuario");

              }

            });

          }

        }

      });

    }

    cback();
  },
  function(cback) {

    console.log("second function series...");

    removerGrupoCompleto();

  }

], function(err) {

  if (err) {
    var error = {
      status: "ERROR"
    };
    generalCallback(null, error);
  }

});
```

Log of what is happening:

```
pegou usuarios do perfil...

first function series...

loop jsonUsuariosPerfil... pedro@.....com.br

second function series..
```

Thanks a lot for all help.

Comment: And you aren't just chaining promises because...?

Comment: Hi Jared, I'm a beginner developer in javascript/ node.js and I didn't know what is this.. I'll search more about the "promises" thank you very much!

Comment: Why was this tagged async-await?

Comment: @pedro.olimpio no problem, we were all beginners at some point: I didn't start programming professionally until I was in my 30s. One thing that you do need to learn though is how to suss out the nature of problems: in this case when you're trying to understand how to structure async code do the *simplest async thing that could work*. Its tempting to just jump in and try to solve the actual problem, but try to discipline yourself to produce a minimal example first.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thank you for your advises, really I managed to solve this issue with a simplest implementation, and was not really necessary to use `async` pack. Thank you again!

Answer (score -1):

Couple of points to take care of:

1. Always call callback, both in case of success as well as error.
2. First argument of callback is error (In most of the cases)
3. Use `async.each` or `async.map` to do asynchronous operation on each element of a collection

---

```
async.each(jsonUsuariosPerfil.users, processUser, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    var error = {
      status: "ERROR"
    };
    return generalCallback(error);
  } else {
    return generalCallback(null); // Always call callback and using with return is a good practice
  }
});

function processUser(usuario, callback) {
  var paramsUsers = {
    Bucket: 's3.....br/.../users/' + usuario.user,
    Key: 'profiles',
  };

  s3.getObject(paramsUsers, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error: " + err);
      const message = "Error getting user -> " + err;
      console.log(message);
      return callback(err);
    }

    var jsonPerfisUsuario = JSON.parse(data.Body);
    var removido = false;
    console.log("found object..." + JSON.stringify(data.Body))
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonPerfisUsuario.profiles.length; i++) {
      var perfil = jsonPerfisUsuario.profiles[i];
      if (perfil.profile == id_grupo) {
        jsonPerfisUsuario.profiles.splice(i, 1);
        removido = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (removido) {
      return removido(usuario, jsonPerfisUsuario, callback);
    }
    return callback();
  });
}

function removido(usuario, jsonPerfisUsuario, callback) {
  var paramsPut = {
    Bucket: 's3.....br/.../users/' + usuario.user,
    Key: 'profiles',
    Body: JSON.stringify(jsonPerfisUsuario)
  };
  console.log("removido, salvando profiles");
  s3.putObject(paramsPut, function(err2, data2) {
    if (err2) {
      console.log("error putting the file:" + err2);
      return callback(err2);
    }
    return callback();
  });
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not the DV, I would guess its because the OP wants the async ops to run in succession, and you're still running them concurrently with `async.each`.